# How to select records based on condition from a list?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

This is my code:

```
for a in soup.select('a[href*="/title/t"]',href=True):
    titles.append(a.text)
print(titles)
```

It is returning the below output.

`[' \n', 'The Shawshank Redemption', ' \n', 'The Godfather', ' \n', 'The Godfather: Part II', ' \n', 'The Dark Knight', ' \n', '12 Angry Men', ' \n', "Schindler's List", ' \n', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', ' \n', 'Pulp Fiction', ' \n', 'Il buono, il brutto, il cattivo', ' \n', 'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring', ' \n', 'Fight Club', ' \n', 'Forrest Gump', ' \n', 'Inception']`

But i want my output without break lines `' \n'`. only the elements of the list should return.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an `if` condition

```
for a in soup.select('a[href*="/title/t"]',href=True):
    if a.text.strip(): titles.append(a.text)
print(titles)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through every second element since it doesn't contain a linebreak.

```
for i in range(1, len(titles), 2):
    titles.append(a.text)
print(titles)
```